# Python return if words are before other words

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to return specific words before other words.
I have cells containing items listed as this:

| Colors | MainColor |
| --- | --- |
| Grey |  |
| Black |  |
| Blue Black |  |
| The item color is White Black |  |

From that table we know that the unique colors are `Grey, Black, Blue and White`. My question is how do I return those unique colors to the `MainColor` column only if they're the first color to appear?

For example:

| Colors | MainColor |
| --- | --- |
| Grey | Grey |
| Black | Black |
| Blue Black | Blue |
| The item color is White Black | White |

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "From that table we know that the unique colors are Grey, Black, Blue and White" - how? Suppose, for example, that I think that `item` should be a color. Why am I wrong? Where does that information come from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), the first match will be taken:

```
df['MainColor'] = df['Color'].str.extract('(Grey|Black|Blue|White)')
```

For full words only:

```
df['MainColor'] = df['Color'].str.extract(r'\b(Grey|Black|Blue|White)\b')
```